# SyntaxError: invalid syntax data.append)=(R)

Tags: python-3.x

Tá dando um erro de sintaxe mas acredito que não seja isso, mas não consigo identificar o que ta de errado:

````
```python
#retorno

df = carteira.copy()
df = df.reset_index()

colunas = df.columns
columns = list(colunas[1:])

df_rent = df(['Date'])
n = len(df_rent)

for coluna in colunas:
  data = [0]
  for idx,val in df.iterrows():
    if idx > 0:
      R = math.log(df.loc[idx,coluna] / (df.loc[idx-1,coluna])
      data.append(R)
      
  df_rent[coluna] = data 
```

>  File "<ipython-input-109-818eeabca8c6>", line 17
    data.append(R)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na linha:

```py
...
R = math.log(df.loc[idx,coluna] / (df.loc[idx-1,coluna])
...
```

Há um `(` que não foi fechado logo após a `/`.  E isto está causando o erro de `Invalid Syntax`.

Basta retirar este parenteses que o erro parará de acontecer:

```py
...
R = math.log(df.loc[idx,coluna] / df.loc[idx-1,coluna])
...
```